# Identifying a Latin abbreviation/symbol

Tags: new-latin, orthography, abbreviations

While transcribing and translating some late 17th century Manorial Court rolls I have come across a frequently recurring symbol. I've referred to Capelli's [The elements of abbreviation in medieval Latin paleography.](https://kuscholarworks.ku.edu/bitstream/handle/1808/1821/47cappelli.pdf?sequence=3) and also [this list of Latin abbreviations](https://archive.org/stream/recordinterprete00martiala), but haven't identified it with any certainty, although it could possibly be **er** for erit/erat.

You can see it here at the end of the last line of this section (after quousque).  The sentence ends 'sed fidelitas sua respectuatur quousque ??', and is referring to the deferral of a minor swearing fealty to a Lord of the Manor.

Is **er** the right interpretation, or have I missed an alternative?

[image]

Transcription of these lines (complete with other unknowns and inevitable errors). 'abb 1' refers to the abbreviation in question.

> [end of last sentence] Et prefat[i] Samuel Joshua et Thomas deder[unt] D[omi]no pro
> fine prout ......(abb 1) Et sic prefat[i]  Samuel per Guardianum suum
> pred[ictum] admissus est inde Ten[en]s sed fidelitas sua respectuatur
> quousq[ue] ......(abb 1)

Comment: Could you provide a transcription of the two (and a bit) lines?

Comment: @CannedMan Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having reviewed other documents containing the same symbol, and their transcriptions and translations, it appears that the symbol in question stands for et cetera.